# How to list a ruby on rails enum attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a class Foo with an enum status:

```
Class Foo  < ApplicationRecord
   enum status: [:not_loaded, :loaded, :stale]
end
```

How do I access the list of status attributes? For example using simple_form I want to do

```
<%= f.input :status, collection: list_of_statuses %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `Foo.statuses` it returns `{ :not_loaded => 0, :loaded => 1, :stale: 2 }`, so you can get list the attributes with `Foo.statuses.keys`. So the simple_form declaration would be

```
<%= f.input :status, collection: DataSet.statuses.keys %>
```